# What Common Mode Choke choose for EMI filtering at 250v

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, inductor, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

I'm designing a PCB with a microcontroller that have to handle 3 Relays. The main power source is an AC Inlet socket 250v, the maximum current for all the circuit from this source is 15A (I included a fuse for that).
Given that I have 2 radio modules in the circuits and I don't want EMI perturbation from this source power I want to add a common mode choke.

What kind of Common Mode Inductor should I use (impedance value, inductance value) and how can I do calculation myself for next time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you doing about conversion from 250V to you 3.3V DC ? Its not clear about how you get there ... It may help to know. Is the 15A the total current being switched by the relays or is this the control circuit consumption including everything else (that would be a little high though ...)

Comment: What spectrum and intensity of EMI is your circuit producing?

Comment: @citizen Thanks for your answer. I'll get the 3.3v and 5v for microcontroller and sensors  from a transformer (HLK-PM01). The 15A is for the all circuit and I want to perfom the noise filtering before any other use (3 relays, convertion for microcontrollers, etc...). Relays have to handle around 4A of load each one

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know how to evaluate that. I just suppose the AC voltage and heavy load may generate lot of noise which could disturb my 2 radios modules on the board

Comment: That’s your starting point. Work out what spectrum and intensity the threat has.

Comment: Before you ask what chokes you need, you should answer where in the circuit you want them. And another thing: just as you want to protect the radios from interference so you want to protect the AC wiring - both power feed and loads - from acting as unintentional antennas that may inadvertently couple noise into the receiver or boost the transmitter’s output gain beyond the certification limits.

Comment: So at first glance, the HLK-PM01 has a 5V dc output at 0.6A. This doesn't do the job for your 15A requirements, but may be enough for the radios etc ... In any case, some comments already mention that you don't know where you want the choke.You may need to consider the specifications of the HLK-PM01 first and see if you need to follow this with some good linear regulators to get your radio power supplies. It may be better to consider the DC inputs to the radios and filter that with say 10 - 20nH. This may/may not be enough but its a start ...

Comment: You may also consider the X2Y cap type filters from Johansen or others on your radio power supply and maybe the radio control lines (say 100pF - 1000pF depending on your radios) as added filters.